# Collection Slider Shows Wrong Slide Count

Tags: javascript, html, json, shopify, liquid

Sup guys,

as contacting the support doesn't help in this concern, I'm asking the community. I'm using spotlight from shopify and the slider pagination is wrong. I've searched and tried to analyze the code but it just doesn't work. Can someone explain me how the total count of slides is determined? It's a counter without js, only liquid. For my case of use I tried to substract 1 count in the span but somehow the class `slider-counter--total` is controlled from outside. I have a total product count of 4 products. On mobile there is 1 item per slide, in total 4 slides but it shows 5. On desktop it's only 3 slides but it shows 4. I would like to fix this on my own but unfortunately I'm not able to determine, which controls the total count of products_to_show. I add the code of the .liquid later on.

I've tried to change

```
 <div class="slider-counter caption">
            <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
            <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display }}</span>
          </div>
```

to

```
 <div class="slider-counter caption">
            <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
            <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display | minus: 1 }}</span>
          </div></span>
```

but unfortunately the class "slider-counter--total" is controlled from outside.
When I change the class name, it works, but then the slider-counter--current doesn't update anymore and whenever I slide it stays on 1. I've thought about making it js on my own but since I don't get along with this code, it's gonna be hard for me.

I've searched through the json values etc. but nothing helped me. Down below I post the full liquid content.

```
{{ 'component-card.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'component-price.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{{ 'component-slider.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'template-collection.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{% if section.settings.image_shape == 'blob' %}
  {{ 'mask-blobs.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{%- endif -%}

{%- if section.settings.enable_quick_add -%}
  {{ 'quick-add.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  <script src="{{ 'quick-add.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'product-form.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
{%- endif -%}

{%- style -%}
  .section-{{ section.id }}-padding {
    padding-top: {{ section.settings.padding_top | times: 0.75 | round: 0 }}px;
    padding-bottom: {{ section.settings.padding_bottom | times: 0.75 | round: 0 }}px;
  }
  footer#footernew{
    display: none;
  }


  main{
    display: flex !Important;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 2000px){
    main{
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
  }
  hr{
    border: 0.25px solid black;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .fixdestages, footer#footermobile.footer-row0{
      display: none !important;
    }   

  }

  
  slider-component.slider-mobile-gutter.slider-component-desktop{
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .slider-buttons.no-js-hidden{
  margin-left: -12px !Important;
  }slider-component#GalleryViewer-template--19556783751492__main

  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    .section-{{ section.id }}-padding {
      padding-top: {{ section.settings.padding_top }}px;
      padding-bottom: {{ section.settings.padding_bottom }}px;
    }
  }
{%- endstyle -%}

{%- liquid
  assign products_to_display = section.settings.collection.all_products_count

  if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > section.settings.products_to_show
    assign products_to_display = section.settings.products_to_show
    assign more_in_collection = true
  endif

  assign columns_mobile_int = section.settings.columns_mobile | plus: 0
  assign show_mobile_slider = false
  if section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and products_to_display > columns_mobile_int
    assign show_mobile_slider = true
  endif

  assign show_desktop_slider = false
  if section.settings.enable_desktop_slider and products_to_display > section.settings.columns_desktop
    assign show_desktop_slider = true
  endif
-%}
<div class="color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }} isolate gradient">
  <div class="collection section-{{ section.id }}-padding{% if section.settings.full_width %} collection--full-width{% endif %}">
    <div class="collection__title title-wrapper title-wrapper--no-top-margin page-width{% if show_mobile_slider %} title-wrapper--self-padded-tablet-down{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider %} collection__title--desktop-slider{% endif %}">
      {%- if section.settings.title != blank -%}
        <h2 class="title inline-richtext {{ section.settings.heading_size }}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
          {{ section.settings.title }}
        </h2>
      {%- endif -%}
      {%- if section.settings.description != blank
        or section.settings.show_description
        and section.settings.collection.description != empty
      -%}
        <div class="collection__description {{ section.settings.description_style }} rte{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
          {%- if section.settings.show_description -%}
            {{ section.settings.collection.description }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ section.settings.description -}}
          {%- endif %}
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>

    <slider-component class="slider-mobile-gutter{% if section.settings.full_width %} slider-component-full-width{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider == false %} page-width{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider == false and section.settings.full_width == false %} page-width-desktop{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider %} slider-component-desktop{% endif %}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
      <ul
        id="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
        class="grid product-grid contains-card contains-card--product{% if settings.card_style == 'standard' %} contains-card--standard{% endif %} grid--{{ section.settings.columns_desktop }}-col-desktop{% if section.settings.collection == blank %} grid--2-col-tablet-down{% else %} grid--{{ section.settings.columns_mobile }}-col-tablet-down{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider %} slider{% if show_desktop_slider %} slider--desktop{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider %} slider--tablet grid--peek{% endif %}{% endif %}"
        role="list"
        aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.name' | t }}"
      >
        {%- for product in section.settings.collection.products limit: section.settings.products_to_show -%}
          <li
            id="Slide-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }}"
            class="grid__item{% if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider %} slider__slide{% endif %}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}"
            {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
              data-cascade
              style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
            {% endif %}
          >
            {% render 'card-product',
              card_product: product,
              media_aspect_ratio: section.settings.image_ratio,
              image_shape: section.settings.image_shape,
              show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
              show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
              show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
              show_quick_add: section.settings.enable_quick_add,
              section_id: section.id
            %}
          </li>
        {%- else -%}
          {%- for i in (1..4) -%}
            <li
              class="grid__item{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}"
              {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
                data-cascade
                style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
              {% endif %}
            >
              {%- assign placeholder_image = 'product-apparel-' | append: forloop.rindex -%}
              {% render 'card-product',
                show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
                placeholder_image: placeholder_image
              %}
            </li>
          {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
      </ul>
      <footer id="footerex">
 <div class="footer-row0">
   <a href="/lookbook" class="lookbook" style="text-decoration: none;">lookbook</a>
   {%- if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider -%}
        <div class="slider-buttons no-js-hidden">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--prev"
            name="previous"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.previous_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
          <div class="slider-counter caption">
            <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
            <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display | minus: 1 }}</span>
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--next"
            name="next"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.next_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
        </div>
  {% else %}
   <a href="/shop" class="shop" style="text-decoration: none;">shop</a>
  {% endif %}

   <a href="/pages/about" class="about" style="text-decoration: none;">about</a>
 </div>
      </footer>
    </slider-component>

    {%- if section.settings.show_view_all and more_in_collection -%}
      <div class="center collection__view-all{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
        <a
          href="{{ section.settings.collection.url }}"
          class="{% if section.settings.view_all_style == 'link' %}link underlined-link{% elsif section.settings.view_all_style == 'solid' %}button{% else %}button button--secondary{% endif %}"
          aria-label="{{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all_label' | t: collection_name: section.settings.collection.title }}"
        >
          {{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all' | t }}
        </a>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
    {% if section.settings.image_shape == 'arch' %}
      {% render 'mask-arch' %}
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="footerex">
<div class="fixdestages">


  
  <div class="seperator">
    <hr>
  </div>
    <div class="footer-row1">
      <a href="/policies/legal-notice" class="legal" style="text-decoration: none;">Legal notice</a>
      <a class="follow" style="text-decoration: none;">Follow Us on</a>
      <a href="/support" class="support" style="text-decoration: none;">Support</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer-row2">
      <a href="/policies/terms-of-service" class="terms" style="text-decoration: none;">terms & conditions</a>
      <a href="https://instagram.com/xdaysleftwear" class="instagram" style="text-decoration: none;">instagram</a>
      <a href="https://tiktok.com/@xdaysleftwear" class="tiktok" style="text-decoration: none;">tiktok</a>
      <a href="/newsletter" class="newsletter" style="text-decoration: none;">newsletter</a>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-row3">
      <a href="/policies/refund-policy" class="shipping" style="text-decoration: none;">shipping & returns</a>
      <a class="payments" style="text-decoration: none;">payment methods</a>
      <a href="/myaccount" class="myaccount" style="text-decoration: none;">myaccount</a>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-row4">
    <a href="/policies/privacy-policy" class="privacy" style="text-decoration: none;">privacy policy</a>
    <ul class="list list-payment" role="list">
              {%- for type in shop.enabled_payment_types -%}
                <li class="list-payment__item">
                  {{ type | payment_type_svg_tag: class: 'icon icon--full-color' }}
                </li>
              {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>


      
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.featured-collection.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "section",
  "disabled_on": {
    "groups": ["header", "footer"]
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "inline_richtext",
      "id": "title",
      "default": "Featured collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.title.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "heading_size",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "h2",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "h1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "h0",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "h1",
      "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "richtext",
      "id": "description",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_description",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_description.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "description_style",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "body",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "subtitle",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "uppercase",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "body"
    },
    {
      "type": "collection",
      "id": "collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.collection.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "products_to_show",
      "min": 2,
      "max": 25,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 4,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.products_to_show.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "columns_desktop",
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 4,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_desktop.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "full_width",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.full_width.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_view_all.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "view_all_style",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "link",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "outline",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "solid",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "solid"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_desktop_slider",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.enable_desktop_slider.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "color_scheme",
      "id": "color_scheme",
      "label": "t:sections.all.colors.label",
      "info": "t:sections.all.colors.has_cards_info",
      "default": "background-1"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.header.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_ratio",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "adapt",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "portrait",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "square",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "adapt",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_shape",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "default",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "arch",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "blob",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "chevronleft",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__4.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "chevronright",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__5.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "diamond",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__6.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "parallelogram",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__7.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "round",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__8.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "default",
      "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.label",
      "info": "t:sections.all.image_shape.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_secondary_image",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_secondary_image.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_vendor.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_rating",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_rating.label",
      "info": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_rating.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_quick_add",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.enable_quick_buy.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.header_mobile.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "columns_mobile",
      "default": "2",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.options__2.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "swipe_on_mobile",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.swipe_on_mobile.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.all.padding.section_padding_heading"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "padding_top",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 4,
      "unit": "px",
      "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_top",
      "default": 36
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "padding_bottom",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 4,
      "unit": "px",
      "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_bottom",
      "default": 36
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.featured-collection.presets.name"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.